# Inherited attribute is not seen

Tags: python

I've got 4 .py files that I'm using for a basic text based game.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out why an attribute is not carrying all the way through like I'd expect.

This method of assigning enemies is fairly round-about, but it's all because of the rest of my game logic.

Here's my code:

**characters.py**

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.hit = 0
```

**enemies.py**

```
from characters import Enemy

class Zombie(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "zombie"
```

**selectors.py**

```
import enemies

def enemysel():
    return enemies.Zombie()
```

**game.py**

```
import selectors

test = selectors.enemysel()
print(test.hit)
```

When I run game.py, I just keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Zombie' object has no attribute 'hit'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to call `super().__init__()` in the subclass.

Comment: Zombie defines its own `__init__()` function, overriding the one from the parent class.

Comment: There is no implicit call to a parent-class constructor in Python. If you override `__init__` it is your responsibility to call the parent-class `__init__`. Note, in a sense, you don't inherit instance attributes in Python. You inherit methods that may define instance attributes.